I want to save only the palette separately
After setting up the palette, I can save it as a startup file and use it.
It is difficult to save it as a startup file after work. I don't want to save my work as a startup file.
I know how to append a palette.
However, this method makes it difficult to manage palettes in an integrated manner.
Is it possible to save the colors added after work to the startup file?
I wish I could save and load the palette as a single file. If you add a color, the file will be overwritten.

You can do it this way:

Save your project file

Create a new file (and DON'T change it)

Append a palette from your project file to the newly created file.

On this step newly created project is equal to (default_file + new_palette)  – so save it as a startup file.



* also I recommend you to name palettes in an obvious way - to not forget the purpose of each of them.

That's a good method. But isn't there a solution that can be solved by just pressing a button?
